# Mupdf viewer text selection

Tags: android, mupdf

so I've been looking at the source code from mupdf android viewer, hoping to make a few changes here and there. 
I wanted to add text selection to it, don't really mind to code the whole thing, but can't find anywhere in the code a hint on how this could be done. Not even with mupdf's official app source code (though it would be easy to check the code and find some reference to it, but I simply don't have a clue how they're handling text selection)
Anyone have any ideas where should I start?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Drawing the text selection can be done similarly to how we draw search results. The main difference is in how you decide what text to highlight.

Using the Java API, get the structured text structure and use that to calculate the list of quads to highlight:

```
StructuredText st = page.toStructuredText();
Point a = <copy first touch down event location>
Point b = <copy current touch event location>
st.snapSelection(a, b, StructuredText.SELECT_WORDS);
Quad qs[] = st.highlight(a, b);
```